# NoClassDefFoundError when importing android directory picker as module

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

im trying to use android directory picker in an application that i am building. this is net.bgreco.DirectoryPicker. my application is called WebDownloader. it seems to run fine. and i am able to launch the directory picker application on its own but when i try to launch it as an activity from my main activity i error mentioned in the title of post.

> 07-15 21:36:58.740
>   31945-31945/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              Process: com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader, PID: 31945
>                                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lnet/bgreco/R$layout;
>                                                                                                  at net.bgreco.DirectoryPicker.onCreate(DirectoryPicker.java:70)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "net.bgreco.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/base.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader-y2pFpZ6io92LNAzJNpMhyw==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
>                                                                                                  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                                                                  at net.bgreco.DirectoryPicker.onCreate(DirectoryPicker.java:70) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

WebDownloader and DirectoryPicker are both the top level folders in my android project structure. here is my app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
compile files('libs/directorypicker.jar')
}
```

and my manifest:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="net.bgreco.DirectoryPicker"/>
</application>

</manifest>`
```

and my manifest for DirectoryPicker:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="net.bgreco"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="1.0.1">

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".DirectoryPicker"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

i am trying to make it so that i can launch the directory picker with an Intent and startActivityForResult. please help me find out what is wrong.

Comment: You can try adding Multidex support and see if the problem persists.